# Switching between SO and AD freezes my Web Browser

Tags: bug, google-chrome, osx

During last 2 weeks I noticed when I switch between `Stack Overflow` and `Ask Different`, it freezes my web browser. Only Chrome's restart returns it back to life.

I'm running Chrome Version 59.0.3071 (official build) on macOS 10.11.6 El Capitan. I'm running 1-2 applications and having just 1 tab opened in Chrome when it freezes.

What should I do to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Only happens for these 2 sites?

Comment: Yes, only these ones. Other sites behave OK.

Comment: Console errors, how much memory is being used by Chrome when it crashes, what were you doing on each site before it crashed?

Comment: I've pasted a printscreen of Activity Monitor.

Comment: Maybe some extension causing this bug? Try this from Incognito Tab

Comment: I don't have any extensions. Also I tried from Incognito. The same!

Comment: @Andy I googled about Chrome freezing on Mac and apparently you're not the only one. There [are](http://yourbusiness.azcentral.com/fix-google-chrome-freezing-mac-11313.html) [some](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/fix-google-chrome-freezing-mac-28508.html) [suggestions](https://macpaw.com/how-to/fix-google-chrome-problems-on-mac) you can try, but this is not a wide bug, and looks like the current secenario is only happens to you (I didn't downvote BTW)

Comment: I am not sure if it could be even the mistake of the website. If a website can hang a browser *intentionally*, imho it is a security hole in the browser. If a website does this *by mistake* then it is a serious *BUG in the browser*.

Answer (score -5):

I'm running Google Chrome Version 59.0.3071.115 on macOS 10.12.5 Sierra and can't reproduce your problem. I think problem occurs from the state of computer. Perhaps you're running too much apps on your computer? Perhaps you've open too much tabs on your browser? Which is -if i'm not mistaken- most common case for chrome to freeze and restart.

Comment: Nope, I'm running just 1-2 apps including Chrome and having just 1 tab in Chrome. It began two weeks ago. Before these 2 weeks it was OK.